# Liferay - documents and media portlet - change value of fileEntry field

Tags: file, liferay, portlet

I want to create my own portlet which presents all FileEntry objects (from Documents and Media) in table with possibility to edit metadata sets. Presentation in table works fine, but I have problem with modify fileEntry.

I try to do this in following way:

```
...
Fields fields = fileToUpdate.getFieldsMap(version).get(uuidFields);
fields.get("myKey").setValue("myVal");
....
```

and after that, I check if field contains properly data:

```
System.out.println(fields.get("myKey").getValue());
```

and unfortunately the value is equals initial data instead: "myVal".

The main problem is, that for some documents it works (I mean value is equals "myVal"), and for others: function Field.setValue() doesn't work.

Can somebody help me with thiat problem, or maybe someone have of dealing with something similar.

regards